# Отображение графом блока обработки исключений

Tags: юнит-тесты, графы, сложность

Изучаю литературу по модульному тестированию. Возник вопрос по определению цикломатического числа программного модуля по графам Мак-Кейба. Дело в том, что он, Мак-Кейб, определяет ряд конструкций, в которых отсутствует блок обработки исключений, а в тестируемом модуле он есть. Таким образом, в распоряжении только это:

[image]

**Вопрос**

Каким образом строить данный граф программного модуля, в котором присутствуют блоки обработки исключений?

**Дополнение**

Тот же вопрос, на всякий случай - для диаграммы Насси-Шнейдермана.

**Дополнение**

Как считаете, данный блок C++ кода ...

```
try {
  Operation1();
  Operation2();
  OperationN();
} catch(Exception1 &e1) {
  Handling1();
} catch(Exception2 &e2) {
  Handling2();
} catch(ExceptionM &em) {
  HandlingM();
} catch(...) {
  Handling();
}
```

... можно ли с некоторым приближением интерпретировать следующей блок-схемой?

[image]

Comment: Фактически, обработку исключений можно отнести к блоку if-then.

Comment: @rjhdby , cейчас дополню вопрос - как раз рисовал))

Comment: Предложенный вами вариант несколько избыточен, потому что содержит, по сути, все возможные варианты пар "операция-исключение". А тем временем не все операции могут вообще выбрасывать исключения, а те, которые могут выбросить, выбросят исключение только какого-то одного типа. В общем, тема сложная и без некоторых упрощений не обойтись. Можете почитать про один из подходов тут (стр. 20-22): http://eclipsefcg.sourceforge.net/Documentation.pdf

Comment: @andreycha , спасибо - гляну.

Comment: Хотя, с другой стороны, на этих графах, похоже, прочерчиваются все возможные варианты, и с этой т.з. вы нарисовали правильно. Остается лишь определиться, как считать сложность. Поскольку никакой информации о том, будет ли исключение и где оно будет, нет, можно только выдать диапазон.

Comment: Считать сложность просто - рисуем граф конкретного модуля, считаем по формуле. В принципе - `catch` блок можно будет и "переключателем" отрисовать на результирующем графе.